Communication difficulties between Telegram and Lambda in Java
I successfully created my first Telegram bot and connected it via webhook to a public API exposed using AWS API Gateway that triggers a lambda written in Java 8.
I verified the connection using CloudWatch, sending a message to the bot and receiving a log written in the lambda.
My problem lies in the lambda code, because although the communication works, it contains information that I believe is wrong.
Let me explain:
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class App implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(Object update, Context context) {

        context.getLogger().log("Object: " + update);

        return 0
    }
}

This is the simple Lambda content that allowed me to get this log:
"Object":{
   version=1.0,
   "resource=/javatest",
   "path=/default/javatest",
   "httpMethod=POST",
   "headers="{
      Content-Length=273,
      "Content-Type=application/json",
      Host=odd9kjkana.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com,
      X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-663158ad-585f95f7491168214c543f33,
      X-Forwarded-For=91.108.6.96,
      X-Forwarded-Port=443,
      "X-Forwarded-Proto=https",
      "accept-encoding=gzip",
      "deflate"
   },
   "multiValueHeaders="{
      "Content-Length="[
         273
      ],
      "Content-Type="[
         "application/json"
      ],
      "Host="[
         odd9kjiaoa.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
      ],
      "X-Amzn-Trace-Id="[
         Root=1-663158ad-585f95f7491168214c543f33
      ],
      "X-Forwarded-For="[
         91.108.6.96
      ],
      "X-Forwarded-Port="[
         443
      ],
      "X-Forwarded-Proto="[
         "https"
      ],
      "accept-encoding="[
         "gzip",
         "deflate"
      ]
   },
   "queryStringParameters=null",
   "multiValueQueryStringParameters=null",
   "requestContext="{
      accountId=891370093172,
      apiId=odd9kjkana,
      domainName=odd9kjkana.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com,
      domainPrefix=odd9kjkana,
      extendedRequestId=XDrLLhT4DoEEPSg=,
      "httpMethod=POST",
      "identity="{
         "accessKey=null",
         "accountId=null",
         "caller=null",
         "cognitoAmr=null",
         "cognitoAuthenticationProvider=null",
         "cognitoAuthenticationType=null",
         "cognitoIdentityId=null",
         "cognitoIdentityPoolId=null",
         "principalOrgId=null",
         sourceIp=91.108.6.96,
         "user=null",
         "userAgent=",
         "userArn=null"
      },
      "path=/default/javatest",
      protocol=HTTP/1.1,
      requestId=XDrLLhT4DoEEPSg=,
      "requestTime=30/Apr/2024":"20":"46":37 +0000,
      requestTimeEpoch=1714509997602,
      "resourceId=ANY /javatest",
      "resourcePath=/javatest",
      "stage=default"
   },
   "pathParameters=null",
   "stageVariables=null",
   "body="{
      "update_id":879419474,
      "message":{
         "message_id":107,
         "from":{
            "id":177801168,
            "is_bot":false,
            "first_name":"Legolas",
            "username":"Sl1me",
            "language_code":"it"
         },
         "chat":{
            "id":177801168,
            "first_name":"Legolas",
            "username":"Sl1me",
            "type":"private"
         },
         "date":1714507808,
         "text":"Test37"
      }
   },
   isBase64Encoded=false
}

While the message I had sent was very different, that 'Test37' found was from a few days ago.
That said, once I understand the correct structure obviously I will have to try to correctly deserialize the object sent by Telegram, for now I need to understand why it returns me an old message and what is the structure I should expect so that I can build the appropriate supporting classes.
Just for completeness, by directly calling the bot via polling (https://api.telegram.org/bot{MY_TOKEN}/getUpdates?offset=-1) I get the result I am looking for, but precisely I want to use webhooks.
I'm trying to consult this guide, but I can't find the problem.
I hope you can help me. Thank you
